# Load infile query issue in mysql

Tags: mysql

We are using Load data infile query to load txt files in the database (mysql) .

we have a continues flow of text files to process using load query and is dumped in the table

but sometimes the load query just stops processing the files ..

we are not able to get what is causing this issue ..

is there anyway we could generate the sql exception or server exception to know what could have caused the problem to distinguish if its a server problem or the file problem ..

Comment: Are you trying to load a file that's being modified at the same time? MySQL is likely to see a partially-written row at the end.

Comment: no... the text file is first loaded into a table and then its moved to the other database..where we do some processing. once the processing is done we empty the first table and then read other text file.

Answer (score 1):

check the following link :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

It will help you in detail about the Load infile query issue in mysql

Comment: jenifer

thanks for your response.

I would like to know if there is anyway i can deduce that if there is a problem in the file or problem with the server if server stops processing or reading a file.

are there any sql errror codes that would tell me that its a mysql server problem or its a file problem

dhairya